# Burning DVD's on Ubuntu (NOT ISO-files)

Tags: dvd, burning

I have a load of self-compiled video dvd's made on Cyberlink PowerDirector which I used to burn to dvd's through Ashampoo Burning Studio 16. These are NOT images of DVD (ie. ISO-files) but instead VIDEO_TS folders with .BUP, .IFO and .VOB -files.

They include custom-made menus, music etc.

Neither programme I used to use (and paid licenses for) sadly seems to work through WINE programmes (tried Crossover and some others). Thus I have already given up of creating more dvd's (for now), but would dearly love to burn the ones I created earlier.

Is there any dvd burner for Ubuntu which handles VIDEO_TS floders instead of ISO images? I have no clue how I would create ISOs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that brasero and tovid work pretty well with VIDEO_TS files
brasero is available in ubuntu repository, so feel free to start with this one.

Comment: Brasero?

Brasero's main menu doesn't even have a suitable option to select for burning VIDEO_TS folder???

Or if it has - then I can't figure out what it is...

Because I am not burning Data Disk, I'm not creating a Video DVD (that work is already done) and I'm not burning an image (as I don't have an image). Those seem to be the only options available in Brasero...???

Comment: well if your VIDEO_TS and AUDIO_TS are already done, just drop them onto the video project dir and burnd it. this also works with k3b and here's detailed tutorial on it: https://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/how-to-burn-video_ts-folders-to-playable-dvds-in-ubuntu-with-k3b/

Answer (score 1):

From Your question you have already have the VIDEO_TS folders so create a TOC (table of contents) so that genisoimage can read it to create the .udf file:

```
dvdauthor -o /parent folder/containing/VIDEO_TS -T
```

Now convert your dvd to the dvd compatible filesystem:

```
genisoimage [-V label] -dvd-video -o output.fs  /parent folder/containing/VIDEO_TS/
```

tip: -dvd-video creates udf filesystem required for video playback

at this point you can go ahead and burn it to a physical dvd:

```
wodim -v dev=/dev/sr0  output.fs
```

where /dev/sr0 is the path to the dvd rom